# Set custom domain for an API using render.com and porkbun

Tags: cookies, dns, custom-domain, render.com

I am trying to upload my api to render.com and use a custom domain for it.

My domain is joses.dev. I bought this domain at Porkbun.

I want to make requests to freshsupportapi.joses.dev.

I already did what render.com is asking.

[render.com instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQbP2.png)

[porkbun dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR7bJ.png)

I'm also using hostinger to host my personal website at joses.dev.

I also changed the default nameservers so joses.dev takes me to the website hosted at hostinger.

I'm getting this error in porkbun when adding DNS records, this might be the problem but if I click yes please update my domain then my website hosted in hostinger is no longer working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bQyx.png)

I added the rules, and used the default nameserver of porkbun, but that makes my website to not work.

The whole purpose of this is using cookies, because with the default domain that render.com offers I can't use cookies.

My app is working perfectly, the only error I'm getting is that the cookies are not being sent to the frontend